# Go: How to unit test a piece of code that works with Mongo collections?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go, go-testing

I am using [the official Mongo driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) for Go. My code looks like this (omitted error handling in order to make the example simpler):

```
type DB struct {
    collection *mongo.Collection
}

func (db DB) GetUsers() []*User {
    res, _ := db.collection.Find(context.TODO(), bson.M{})
    var users []*User
    res.All(context.TODO(), &users)
    return users
}
```

**Question:** How to unit test the `GetUsers` function?

I went through [the driver's documentation](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver) and didn't find any testing related functionality/best practices.

*Note:* The full code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/Shpota/skmz/blob/master/server/db/db.go).

Answer (score 4):

You can't unit test connectivity to a database, by definition - that would be an integration test. To my mind, this method is too simple to bother testing with a mock MongoDB; instead, the most value would probably be from a combination of:

1. A mock `DB` type that consumers can use for their unit tests without hitting MongoDB.
2. An *integration* test of the `DB` type itself, that hits a real test Mongo database - this could be a test database created and filled by the test suite, and destroyed after tests are completed (which would be my recommendation).

Comment: Thank you. But I am interested particularly in **unit testing**. For instance, if you open the original code on GitHub, there is also an error handling logic which is better testable with unit tests.

Comment: Then you'll have to mock the Mongo driver itself.